# Two child components pass data to the same parent with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, emit

I'm now using an api traveling data and want to show it with pagination and at the same time show the data with prefered sorting method. I'm trying to make everything into three components:

1. pagination -- for the buttons of pages
2. sortbar -- for sorting the traveling data
3. view -- showing the corresponding data according to the two component above. ex. page.10 and sort by price descending

And what I'm doing is to put the 1 and 2 components inside the third, which means 1 and two are both child of 3, and once the props inside the child components have been changed （pageNumber and sort), pass them to the parent and use $watch to execute function for requesting API once detecting the change of data pageNumber and sort.

While, the problem I'm facing now is that I found it seems I can only pass data from one of the two child to the parent, if one passed successfully then the other failed, and it depends on the order of me putting child inside the parent.

I'm just wondering if it's possible to send data from two child components to one parent at the same time? thank you for your help!

below is my code:

1. pagination

```
    <template>
        <div class="pagination">
            <div class="pagination-row">
                <!-- previous page button -->
                <button class="btn btn-light" @click = "previouspage"> &lt; </button>
                <!-- pagination button --> 
                <span v-for= "(item, index) in new Array(10)" :key="index">
                    <button class="btn btn-light"  @click = "resetpage(index)">{{ index+1 }}</button>
                </span> 
                <!-- next page button -->
                <button class="btn btn-light" @click = "nextpage"> &gt; </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
      
    <script>
      export default {
        name: "pagination",
        props: {
            pageNumber:{ 
                type: Number,
            }
        },
    
        methods: {
            resetpage(index) {
                this.pageNumber = index + 1;
                console.log(this.pageNumber)
                //use 'update:"props-name"' to emit a update event, and pass the change value.
                this.$emit('update:pageNumber', this.pageNumber); //子元件與父元件雙向綁定
            },
    
            nextpage() {
                this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
                this.$emit('update:pageNumber', this.pageNumber);
            },
    
            previouspage() {
                this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber - 1;
                this.$emit('update:pageNumber', this.pageNumber);
            },
        }
      };
    </script>
```

2. sortbar

```
    <template>
        <div class="sortbar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light" style="width:100%; margin: auto;"> 
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      price：{{ pricesort }}
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item btn" @click="price_desc" href="#">low->high</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item btn" @click="price_asc" href="#">high->low</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      評分：{{ratingsort}}
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item btn" @click="rating_desc" href="#">high->low</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item btn" @click="rating_asc" href="#">low->high</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav> 
        </div>
    </template>
      
      <script>
      export default {
        name: "sortbar",
        props: {
          sort: {
            type: String,
          }
        },
        data() {
          return{
            pricesort: 'low->high',
            ratingsort: ''
          }
          },
        methods: {
          price_desc(){
            this.sort = 'price_desc';
            this.pricesort = 'high->low'
            this.ratingsort = ''
            //use 'update:"props-name"' to emit a update event, and pass the change value.
            this.$emit('update:sort', this.sort); 
          },
      
          price_asc(){
            this.sort = 'price_asc';
            this.pricesort = 'high->low'
            this.ratingsort = ''
            this.$emit('update:sort', this.sort);
          },
      
          rating_desc(){
            this.sort = 'rating_desc';
            this.ratingsort = 'high->low'
            this.pricesort = ''
            this.$emit('update:sort', this.sort);
          },
      
          rating_asc(){
            this.sort = 'rating_asc'
            this.ratingsort = 'low->high'
            this.pricesort = ''
            this.$emit('update:sort', this.sort);
          },
        }
      };
      </script>
```

3. view

```
    <template>
        <div class="groupdata">
          <!-- use `.sync` decorator to declare the counter is a two way binding props. -->
          <Sortbar :sort.sync="sort"></Sortbar>
          <Pagination :pageNumber.sync="pageNumber"></Pagination>
          {{ pageNumber }}
          {{ sort }}
          <div class="container">
            <div  v-for = "(item, index) in data" :key="index">
              <div class = "cards">
                <div class = 'img' style="width: 25%; height: 100%">
                  <img :src="item.image_url" style="width:100%; 
                  height:100%; 
                  object-fit:cover; ">
                </div>
                <div class='info' style="width: 75%; margin: auto;">
                  <h5 class = 'agency'>
                    {{ item.agency }} {{ item.rating | rating }}
                  </h5>
                  <h5 class = 'title'>
                    {{ item.title }}
                  </h5>
                  <div style="display: flex; padding-left: 20px;">
                    <div v-for = "(tag, index) in item.tags" :key="index">
                      <button class='tags'>{{ tag }}</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr style="margin: 5px 0px;">
                  <div class='timeandnum'>
                    <div style="width: 75%; display: flex; align-items: center;">
                      <div v-for = "(option, index) in item.group" :key="index" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <p class='date'>{{ option.date | date }} ( {{ option.date | day}} )</p>
                        <button class='num'> 可售{{ option.quantity }}位</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 25%;  margin-left: 20px;">
                      <p style="color:rgb(253, 163, 60); font-size: 1.8em; display: inline; font-weight: bold;">{{ item.tour_days }}</p>
                      <p style="font-size: 1em; display: inline;">天</p>
                      <p style="color:rgb(253, 163, 60); font-size: 1.8em; display: inline; font-weight: bold;">{{ item.min_price | currency }}</p>
                      <p style="font-size: 1em; display: inline;">元起</p>
                    </div>    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <loading :active.sync="isloading"></loading>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
      
      <script>
      import axios from "axios";
      import Pagination from "./Pagination"
      import Sortbar from "./Sortbar"
      
      export default {
        name: "groupdata",
        components: {
          Pagination, Sortbar
        },
        data() {
          return {
            isloading: false,
            data: [],
            sort: 'price_desc',
            pageNumber: 1
          } 
        },
    
        //用watch監聽pageNumber這個data被更新的時候執行function
        watch: {
          pageNumber: function(){
            this.getdata(this.pageNumber,10, this.sort)
          },
          sort: function(){
            this.getdata(1,10, this.sort)
          }
        },
        created() {
          this.getdata(this.pageNumber,10, this.sort);
        },
      
        methods: {
          async getdata(page,rpp,sort) {
            try{
            this.data = [];
            this.isloading = true;
            let tourdata = await axios
            .get(`http://interview.tripresso.com/tour/search?page=${page}&row_per_page=${rpp}&sort=${sort}`)
            this.data = tourdata.data.data.tour_list;
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } finally {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.isloading = false
              },500)
          };  
          },
          updateSort(val) {
            this.sort = val;
          }
        }
      };
      </script>
```

Comment: You are not permitted to change the prop's value. this.pageNumber = index + 1;, this.sort = 'price_desc';  ...
update/sync does their job properly and there is no need to try to change props value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Actually I saw the error about that I should build data for not changing props, while initially it did't work after I did the change, but then I found it was caused by syntax error which I could't have found for more than half day (it sometimes happens....)